# How makefile finds this target

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with the following lines:

```
elf: $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
lss: $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).lss 
sym: $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).sym
hex: $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
bin: $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).bin
```

As for my understanding, `elf:` is the target and depends on the file `$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf`. If this (`.elf`) file is not up to date, what is make going to do as I don't see a command to execute? So is the case with lss, sym etc. Thanks.

Kamesh

Answer (score 0):

You are close, maybe some additional infos help:

- `elf:` is just *one* of many targets. When called without a specific target `make` chooses the first target definition it encounters in a Makefile.
- `$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf` is indeed the targets dependency. It does not have to be a file, it can also be another target in this or another Makefile. It just has to be defined. In that case that secondary target may define built rules leading to actions...
- `make` has a builtin ruleset it applies when no rules are implemented for a given target. This is one of the reasons why targets without built rules do make sense and may trigger an action.
- there might be additional 'default rules' defined in the Makefile that apply.
- often such 'virtual targets' are only defined to be able to issue a simple and clean make command. Their purpose is just to trigger secondary targets via their dependencies.

In general it is a good idea to use the verbose mode of `make` to see the tree of actions it takes. Also, when looking for more detailed information you should consult the "info pages" about the topic 'make': `info make` on any decend unixoid system (if the info pages are installed).

Comment: if the dependency $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf is another target, can it have wild cards like %.elf:

Comment: It definitely can have wildcards, though I am currently not sure about the syntax (has been a few years since I extensively wrote Makefiles...). As said: consult the excellent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply the whole Makefile(s) so it is not possible to answer with absolute certainty.  However, from experience, the lines you show mean as follows.

`elf` is an "phony" target - that means, is not meant as a name of a real file, but as an abbreviation either of a collection of real files, or one real file with a longer name.

The "rule"

```
elf: $(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
```

means, to `make elf`, first update `$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf`. After that, the rule has nothing else in it, so there is nothing more to do.

In this way, your phony `elf` target, is equivalent to the file `$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET).elf`. That file, probably has another rule elsewhere in the makefile, that says how to make it.

Similarly for your other phony targets.

```
>make elf
```

will just update that file `$(OUTDIR)/$(TARGET`